# call container B inside container A using docker networks

Tags: docker, networking

- I have two docker containers A and B that runs on the same user-defined network.
- Container A has a port published, container B hasnt.
- I do my requests on container's A published port, but container A needs to do requests on container B.
- The requests to B inside A are mapped to `0.0.0.0:(container B needed port)/route`.
- These fails.

How could I call B inside A without getting and changing IP based on the network every time?

Comment: by using the container name as the hostname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a [user-defined network](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) set to bridge, you can access other containers by their container's name which is automatically as hostname for containers inside same network.

So from `containerA` you could do `ping containerB` without problems. In your case it would be changing the setting to `containerB_name:(container B needed port)/route`